# JSON error on Logcat. Cant find what the error is from Logcat

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse JSON in my app.

My JSONParser.java is as follows.

```
public class JSONParser { 
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";


    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

I have the JSON sent to the device from here
http://ketozen.com/ketorecipes/

Here is the pastebin output
http://pastebin.com/s1M8HzNr

This is in my log.
http://pastebin.com/QTUphjeR

Could someone please shed some light on where the problem is ?

Comment: is getJSONFromUrl run on the Ui Thread?

Comment: Your logcat is ok. But you should remove `Log.e("JSON", json);`. Why do you log error after the successful result?

Comment: printStackTrace rather than log e.toString.

Comment: you log is this line `Log.e("JSON", json);`

Comment: i don't get it. there are no errors in the logcat (appart from the obvious above, which is not an error). Your code appears to work, doesn't it ?

Comment: can people stop using iso8859-1 to read json ? json is **utf-8**. You'll have trouble if you keep doing that. Also, there is the much more efficient EntityUtils, to read the content of an HttpEntity in one line. I don't get why people use readLine. a line is quite an arbitrary delimiter that isn't required to have the same size for everyone.

Comment: Your log cat looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sb.append(line + "n");
```

probably you meant to write

```
sb.append(line + "\n");
```

Also EntityUtils has the static method `toString(entity))`. You can get directly your `String`
in this way

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

and then

```
try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
 } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
 }
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you. I am a beginner so was unaware of the Entityutils. I will append this on my code. Also thanks for catching that \n error. I was quite oblivious to it.  Do you have anymore suggestions on the code.

Comment: use EntityUtils istead of BufferRead , this time :)